# how to switch task and shelve/unshelve changes automatically

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij's IDEA tasks&contexts feature: I usually work on several tasks a day and I need to switch among them by saving and associating uncommitted changes to a task: this way, when I switch task, I have a clean slate and/or I can get back the status I was working on without shelve/unshelve as a second mechanical step, which is cumbersome.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible.

There is a feature request, please feel free to vote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210486/Auto-shelving-and-auto-unshelving-when-Task-switching